# Linear to Array

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to teach myself about Arrays. Can someone translate the below code using an Array and explain?

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 100

If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i) < Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1") Then
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i) = "Less than"

ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i) > Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1") Then
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i) = "Greater than"

Else: Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i) = "Equal to"

End If


Next i
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you searched Google on `Arrays`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code uses an array to store the results that you might give based on a comparison of cells in columns A & B...

```
Option Explicit

Sub marine()
    Dim rowNumber As Integer

    ' create an array of strings here
    Dim values(-1 To 1) As String

    ' populate the values
    values(-1) = "less than"
    values(0) = "equal to"
    values(1) = "greater than"


    For rowNumber = 1 To 100
        Dim signValue As Integer
        signValue = Math.Sgn(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowNumber, 1) - Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowNumber, 2))

        ' copy the correct value from the array into the cell
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowNumber, 3).Value = values(signValue)
    Next rowNumber
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I assigned some values to column B and this worked great.